# How to create loop for conditions

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

I need to create a loop every 1000 times and change the variable every next time

If I use the condition below it works, but I need to create a loop.

```
long x = 0;
bool y = true;

if (x < 1000) { y = true; }
if (x > 1000 && x < 2000 ) { y = false; }
if (x > 2000 && x < 3000 ) { y = true; }
...
```

Comment: Do you know how to make a loop in c#?

Answer (score 4):

With this, you will switch the `y` value every 1000 iterations (mod operator - or `%` - checks the division's reminder by 1000, in this case. If 0, `x` is a multiple of 1000).

```
for (int x = 0; x < 3000; x++){
     if (x % 1000 == 0) y = !y;
     //... your other instructions
}
```